# DatePicker in antd throwing error import dayjsGenerateConfig from 'rc-picker/lib/generate/dayjs' was not found

Tags: datepicker, antd

After cloning the fresh project and installing all dependencies  test fail with the following error

> **This dependency was not found:**
>
> rc-picker/lib/generate/dayjs in ./node_modules/@rjsf/antd/dist/es/components/DatePicker/index.js

```
import dayjsGenerateConfig from 'rc-picker/lib/generate/dayjs';
import generatePicker from 'antd/lib/date-picker/generatePicker';
var DatePicker = generatePicker(dayjsGenerateConfig);
export default DatePicker;
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the above issue by replacing the URL

> import dayjsGenerateConfig from 'rc-picker/lib/generate/dayjs';

to

> import  dayjsGenerateConfig from
> 'antd/node_modules/rc-picker/lib/generate/dayjs'

code will look like this

```
import  dayjsGenerateConfig from 'antd/node_modules/rc-picker/lib/generate/dayjs'
import generatePicker from 'antd/lib/date-picker/generatePicker';
var DatePicker = generatePicker(dayjsGenerateConfig);
export default DatePicker;
```